# No reaction when writing own Gstreamer script

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I am trying to get a good understand on how to write your own gstreamer applications. Iam currently writing on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

The problem is that i cant even get the Hello World example working on my system:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling works totally fine with:

```
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

But when i execute the compiled file with:

```
./helloworld
```

Nothing is happening. Not a single message is printed in the console. I even added printf("test"); to the file and this is also NOT displayed. I also added an error, to see if the compiler is working, and the compiler shows correctly the mistake (-> iam not writing to the wrong file).

PS: i think i correctly installed Gstreamer, because i can execute

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

without a problem.

Whats the problem?

Comment: As you launch your process, `gst_init (&argc, &argv);` can be `gst_init (NULL, NULL);`

Comment: could you tell me what this means for me? I am not that familliar with C in general. Does this mean that my gst_init is always failing on start?

Comment: Where did you put `printf`? In which point of code?

Comment: before   /* Initialize GStreamer */

Comment: Try using `printf("test\n");`

Comment: The program is now working correctly. Before it didnt. I changed the printf back and its still working. EDIT: iam really confused, as it looks like i didnt had any problem before. Welp. Thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: Well. Cancel the question so.

Comment: I have the same problem too, i compile this code but it shows error "Illegal instruction: 4' does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

The code you pasted works as expected.

You probably are using headless i.e. via ssh or something similar.

What happens is it opens a new window and displays a short clip, since you are viewing via ssh you won't be able to see it.

Add the below print statement after main() before Build the pipeline and check whether it prints or not.

```
  g_print("Hello World!");
```

or

```
 g_printerr("Hello World!");
```